# Session or Model Field in Django?

Tags: django, session

I'm a beginner in Django. When developing an app, I want to fulfill the following functionality: There is some pictures in one webpage. A user can 'like' a picture by clicking a button bellow it. But one user can only like a specific picture once.

Now there seem two methods to do this.

1) Set an attribute in the session. So I when a user click a button, I can check if he has already 'liked' this picutre according to this session.

2) Add a new field in my user's model to record which pictures he has 'liked'.

Then I don't know which one to use. My questions are as follows:

- For method (1), session can expire after some time (e.g. 2 weeks).
  So for a user who revisits my website after 2 weeks, is it true that
  I can not prevent him from re-liking the picture he's already 'liked'
  before?
- If I want to have access to the info about which pictures a user
  has 'liked', is it true that I can only use method (2) to store this 
  information?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the "favorites" to persist across multiple sessions, then yes, you need to store the data somewhere that isn't volatile. A simple solution is to use a separate model, a `LikedPicture` for example:

```
class LikedPicture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_index=True)
    picture = models.ForeignKey(Picture)
```

Session expired? No problem, just get the ones they've liked from the model. You could take it a step further and make the related model [generic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations), so you don't have to make a separate model to hold each association, if you have several different models you're going to associate similarly.

Want to make sure the user only favorites something once? Django makes this ridiculously easy with [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
favorited_picture, created = FavoritedPicture.objects.get_or_create(user=user,
    picture=picture, defaults={'user': user, 'picture': picture})
```

I find this method to be much more straightforward than trying to maintain a [comma-separated-field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#commaseparatedintegerfield) on a model to store the ids of the favorited things.

Comment: Thank you very much! I do learn a lot from your answer, especially the Contenttype framework,which is a really exciting solution!!!